# Regex to mask characters except first two and last two characters in Java

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I want to write a regular expression to do the following:
source string: `abcdefg`
output string: `ab***fg`

source string: `123456789`
output string: `12*****89`

source string: `a123d`
output string: `a1*3d`

Comment: Does the amount of `*` in the middle *need* to reflect the substitution length?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(?<!^.?).(?!.?$)
```

The idea is:

- `(?<!)` - a *negative lookbehind* to ensure that
- `^.?` - the *start of the string* is not *zero or one characters* away
- `.` - the character that is going to be replaced
- `(?!)` - a *negative lookahead* to ensure that
- `.?$` - the *end of the string* is not *zero or one characters* away

Replace with single `*`.

Comment: cool, i leaved this path cause lookbehind does not accept variable size on pcre (default on regex101). One point for java regex engine

Comment: @GiuseppeRicupero, yep, in java you can have lookbehinds with variable length as long as they are bound by finite length. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

**Find**: `(?<=..).(?=..)`
**Replace**: `*`

*Details*:

- `(?<=..)` - a positive lookbehind that requires any two chars other than line break chars immediately to the leftht of the current location
- `.` - any char other than a line break char
- `(?=..)` - a positive lookahead that requires any two chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC4dg3/1).

Here are solutions for some languages:

- [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `text.replaceAll("(?<=..).(?=..)", "*")`
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - `text.replace(/(?<=..).(?=..)/g, "*")`
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `re.sub(r"(?<=..).(?=..)", "*", text)`
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) - `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=..).(?=..)", "*")`
- [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) - `Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=..).(?=..)", "*")`
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) - `text.gsub(/(?<=..).(?=..)/, "*")`
- [r](/questions/tagged/r) - `gsub("(?<=..).(?=..)", "*", text, perl=TRUE)`
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) - `preg_replace('~(?<=..).(?=..)~', '*', $text)`
- [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) - `$text =~ s/(?<=..).(?=..)/*/g;`
- [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) - `REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '(?<=..).(?=..)', '*','g')`

Answer (score 1):

The following code use the regex `(.{2})(.*)(.{2})` to do exactly what you asks (works with string from `5` chars above):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String input = "1234567890";

final Pattern hidePattern = Pattern.compile("(.{1,2})(.*)(.{1,2})");
Matcher m = hidePattern.matcher(input);
String output;

if(m.find()) {
  l = m.group(2).length();
  output = m.group(1) + new String(new char[l]).replace("\0", "*") + m.group(3);
}

System.out.println(output); // 12******90
```

If you need to allow less then `5` chars (till `3` below does not make sense) use:

```
(.{1,2})(.+)(.{1,2})
```

Answer (score 0):

\A.{2}(.+).{2}\z will return you what you want. Will not work if less than 5 characters. This is language dependent. My regex is in ruby. In ruby:

\A => start of string
\z => end of string

find your language equivalents.

Comment: What is the `z` flag? What flavour of regex? OP hasn't defined his language yet

Comment: `\z` is a metacharacter, not a flag; it matches the end of the string; so it matches only at the end of the last line in a multi-line string.