# Masking phone number Java

Tags: java, regex, masking

I need to mask the phone number. it may consist of the digits, + (for country code) and dashes. The country code may consist of 1 or more digits. I have created such kind of regular expression to mask all the digits except the last 4:

```
inputPhoneNum.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*");
```

For such input: **+13334445678**

I get this result: **+*******5678**

However, it doesn't work for such input: **+1-333-444-5678**
In particular, it returns just the same number without any change. While the desired output is masking all the digits except for the last 4, plus sign and dashes.
That is why I was wondering how I can change my regular expression to include dashes? I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Is the expected output for the second number `+*-***-***-5678`?

Comment: Is `+1-23-45-67` a case that should be considered and how should it be masked if so?

Comment: Check this solution will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675260/regex-to-mask-characters-except-first-two-and-last-two-characters-in-java

Comment: I meant `.replaceAll("\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})", "*")`, but no idea if it is what you need, really.

Comment: @SebastianProske this case should not be considered. The main idea is that there are ***-**** such digits in the end and the beginning with country code may differ

Answer (score 17):

Use this regex for searching:

```
.(?=.{4})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldMIjK/1)

Difference is that `.` will match any character not just a digit as in your regex.

**Java code:**

```
inputPhoneNum = inputPhoneNum.replaceAll(".(?=.{4})", "*");
```

---

However if your intent is to mask **all digits before** last 4 digits then use:

```
.(?=(?:\D*\d){4})
```

Or in Java:

```
inputPhoneNum = inputPhoneNum.replaceAll("\\d(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})", "*");
```

`(?=(?:\\D*\\d){4})` is a positive lookahead that asserts presence of at least 4 digits ahead that may be separated by 0 or more non-digits.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ldMIjK/3)

Comment: So `123-465-789` will mask everything but `-789` instead of "_all the digits except the last 4_"

Comment: I don't know every phone format but it is probably valid somewhere ;) here we have a format like `0123-45-67-89`.

Comment: You are still masking the initial `+` and all `-` in the number (though OP did not specify the correct behaviour for this).

Comment: Yes because OP wrote: `While the desired output is masking all the digits except for the last 4, plus sign and dashes`

Comment: I like that solution even if you just said that `+`, `-` and last 4 digit should still be visible ;) but I still like the solution. (and just need to replace `.` with `\d` to match that requirements)

Comment: @anubhava I read that as _don't remove the last 4 digits, plus and dashes_, but might be wrong here. OPs sample at least shows that the plus should be left in place.

Comment: Can you provide regex which keeps the area code and masks the rest ?

Comment: @AnirudhKashyap Area code is not always 3 digits. You can do that using substring and replace as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not good in RegEx but I think you should normalize the phone numbers by getting rid of `-`occurences :

```
   inputPhoneNum = inputPhoneNum.replace("-","").replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*");
```

Comment: You may remove hyphens without a regex, `.replaceAll("\\-","")` => `.replace("-","")`. BTW, there is no need escaping `-` in a regex when outside a character class.

Comment: @mustabelMo not really, not using a `Regex` is simpler/faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use two replace all non digit or + with empty then use your regex :

```
"+1-333-444-5678".replaceAll("[^\\d\\+]", "").replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*");
```

Output

```
+*******5678
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
".*\\d(?=\\d{4})","*"
```

You can try creating by hit and trial using [this website](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

*If* you don't want to use `regex`, an alternate solution would be to loop through the `String` with a `StringBuilder` from end to start, and append the first 4 digits and then `*` after that (and just append any non-digit characters as normal)

```
public static String lastFour(String s) {
        StringBuilder lastFour = new StringBuilder();
        int check = 0;
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                check++;
            }
            if (check <= 4) {
                lastFour.append(s.charAt(i));
            } else {
                lastFour.append(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) ? "*" : s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return lastFour.reverse().toString();
    }
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/jfV5Ac)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used, it may be useful, just masks some digits in the provided number

```
 /*
 * mask mobile number .
 */
public  String maskMobileNumber(String mobile) {
    final String mask = "*******";
    mobile = mobile == null ? mask : mobile;
    final int lengthOfMobileNumber = mobile.length();
    if (lengthOfMobileNumber > 2) {
        final int maskLen = Math.min(Math.max(lengthOfMobileNumber / 2, 2), 6);
        final int start = (lengthOfMobileNumber - maskLen) / 2;
        return mobile.substring(0, start) + mask.substring(0, maskLen) + mobile.substring(start + maskLen);
    }
    return mobile;
}
```